# How to overlap view on ListActivity that has a custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one `ListActivity` on which i want to overlap one transparent view. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RelativeLayout ViewGroup to overlay views.
Pseudocode:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <View main ...>
    <View overlay ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For transparency you can call setAlpha(), depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using framelayout.because framelayout.